# Guidewire PolicyCenter The object you are trying to update was changed by another user. Please try your change again

Tags: guidewire, gosu

I'm having this weard mistake "The object you are trying to update was changed by another user. Please try your change again." I would like to know what is the reason of this without context. There are no logs about it, no exception stacktrace, no information about this mistake in documentation. I believe this is something about Bundles but I want to now the exact reason

Answer (score 0):

GW throws several exceptions related, by example ConcurrentDataChangeException, DBVersionConflictException depending of entity type. It occurs when a bean is modified concurrent by two or more transactions (bundle).

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens because on one bundle two transaction changes are trying to commit where prior bundle is still not committed.
Let us understand with one example- There is user which does a policy change to add any contact or any other business operation. And at the same time another user open same transaction in his GW PC UI and tries to do some business operation at this GW system throws this error on UI because the pervious bundle is still not committed.
The error trace leads you to some OOTB java classed and I think you can get it from PCLogs from PC UI Server logs.
Hopes this clarifies you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happens because your object was updated by someone else on the DB during your db read from the DB and your attempt to write it back into the DB.

GW does this by leveraging the version check from your database object.

The exception message actually tells you who and when did the conflicting update. There're no stack traces that will point you to the cause of the other update.

Root causes might be several - from distributed cache in clustered env going out of sync to actually having some other party doing work on the same entities as you do. So the fix is per case really.